# PHP: create a cookie from Google Adword campaign keyword URL

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, input, google-ads-api

I am using PHP on a Wordpress site to do this. If you think JavaScript or jQuery would be better, let me know.

One of our partners is running Google Google Adword campaigns for us. I don't have access to the exact campaign URLs so I can't create cookies based on knowing the campaign URLs. The business owner wants to track which campaign users came from when they submit a form on our site. My plan:

1. I want to set/name a cookie based on Google Adword campaign keyword URL.
2. If a cookie is set from a previous campaign and the user clicks on a new campaign I want to remove the previous campaign cookie (if it exists) and create a cookie from the new campaign.
3. If this cookie is set - and they are on the form page - I want to load a hidden input with the cookie name in the value attribute - and when the form is submitted, that hidden field would tell us which campaign they came from.

Here is an example of an Adword campaign URL our partner is using:

?UTM_keyword=field%20service%20software_phrase&UTM_source=Paid%20Search&gclid=EAIaI

What I am trying to do is grab the portion of the above URL between "?UTM_keyword=" and "&UTM_source=" - in this case, it would be "field%20service%20software_phrase".

Here is the code I've developed so far:

header.php - after `<!DOCTYPE html>` on every page

```
<?php
// load content-utm.php if the URI contains UTM_keyword
    if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "UTM_keyword")){
// load content-utm.php
        get_template_part( 'content', 'utm' );
    }
?>
```

content-utm.php

```
<?php
    $uriSegments = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY);
// strip out UTM_keyword=
    $uriSegments2 = substr($uriSegments, 12);
// strip out everything after &UTM_source= including &UTM_source=
    $uriSegments3 = substr($uriSegments2, 0, strpos($uriSegments2, "&UTM_source="));
    $_SESSION['uriName'] = $uriSegments3;
// create a cookie
    if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $uriSegments3)){
        $cookie_name = $uriSegments3;
        $cookie_value = "UTM";
// make it a session cookie that expires after the browser is closed
        setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, 0, "/");
    }
// I know how to remove a cookie but I'm not sure how I would remove THIS type of cookie
?>
```

form-page.php

```
<?php
// if the cookie is set
    if (isset($_COOKIE[$uriSegments3])){
// load content-deluxe-cookie-tracking.php
        get_template_part( 'partners/content', 'deluxe-cookie-tracking' );
    } 
?>
```

content-deluxe-cookie-tracking.php

```
<input type="hidden" id="1234567890" name="1234567890" value="<?php echo $uriSegments3 = $_SESSION['uriName']; ?>">
```

So far:

1. I have been able to create a cookie that persists as long as the browser is open and expires when it closes - which is what I want.
2. If the campaign URL is in the address bar then the "if" statement in `form-page.php` returns true, 
   `content-deluxe-cookie-tracking.php` loads and the input `value="<?php echo $uriSegments3 = $_SESSION['uriName']; ?>"` is the cookie name.
3. BUT, if the campaign is on another page and the user gets to the form page where there is no campaign URL, then the "if" statement in `form-page.php` returns false, 
   `content-deluxe-cookie-tracking.php` doesn't load - and I have checked to make sure the cookie exists.

So, for example:

www.mysitename.com/form-page/?UTM_keyword=field%20service%20software_phrase&UTM_source=Paid%20Search&gclid=EAIaI

works, but:

www.mysitename.com/form-page/

doesn't work, even if the cookie gets set on another page, for example:

www.mysitename.com/another-page/?UTM_keyword=field%20service%20software_phrase&UTM_source=Paid%20Search&gclid=EAIaI

Comment: Right now I'm looking at stackoverflow.com/questions/27758053/… and I think I needed: session_start(); at the beginning of the header.php and then in content.php I needed to test if $_SESSION["uriName"]) is true instead of seeing if a cookie exists. Creating a session for uriName and tracking that across the site did the trick. My final solution won't include a cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My final solution to my own problem is to use a php $_SESSION instead of a cookie. Through this solution I can create a session that:

1. Can save the campaign keyword data as a named session
2. The session persists as long as the browser is open
3. The session persists on every page so the user can go to other pages
4. The session persists if the site is opened in a new tab
5. The session be used to load a hidden input and populate that hidden input value attribute so it can be sent along with the form to CRM software
6. Every time a new campaign is used, the session will update with the new campaign keyword information. Campaigns can be created on any page and be tracked on any page.

header.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Header
*/
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
// if the URI contains UTM_keyword
    if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "UTM_keyword")){
// load content-utm.php
        get_template_part( 'content', 'utm' );
    }
?>
```

content-utm.php

```
<?php
// parse the URI after the question mark (?)
    $uriSegments = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY);
// strip out UTM_keyword=
    $uriSegments2 = substr($uriSegments, 12);
// strip out everything after &UTM_source= including &UTM_source=
    $uriSegments3 = substr($uriSegments2, 0, strpos($uriSegments2, "&UTM_source="));
// name the session I can reference later
    $_SESSION['uriName'] = $uriSegments3;
?>
```

form-page.php

```
<?php
// if the session named uriName is set
    if (isset(isset($_SESSION["uriName"])){
// load content-deluxe-cookie-tracking.php
        get_template_part( 'partners/content', 'deluxe-cookie-tracking' );
    } 
?>
```

content-deluxe-cookie-tracking.php

```
// echo the value of the session in the input
<input type="hidden" id="1234567890" name="1234567890" value="<?php echo $uriSegments3 = $_SESSION['uriName']; ?>">
```

Submit form and data ends up in a CRM field created to retrieve this data.

Comment: Very clever, I was going to program a solution like yours today. Before start I decided to look if someone was done anything similar voilá, I believe your solution is a clever one.